# Список файлов в каталоге Яндекс Диска

Tags: python, yandex-disk

```
import yadisk
y = yadisk.YaDisk(token=co.yadisk_token)
print(list(y.get_files(limit = 2)))
```

такой код выдает мне

```
[<ResourceObject{'antivirus_status': 'clean', 'file': 'https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/disk/7d4240c806fcb517afb9946eca2328b9b89a33ca89aa94dc41d6d1ffea676330/635f0cda/FjQNTsGv4s3eeXJJrN-rXQBbwgvsQ5-bygQCdhCFXsMfgUHFYubqRaIPYDt55Ms3nNZ0BSyBqp7iK2PFhF60sg%3D%3D?uid=372337915&filename=1.JPG&disposition=attachment&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fjpeg&owner_uid=372337915&fsize=5427274&hid=f0015d6a72e5e7827d46c90b00ddf99f&media_type=image&tknv=v2&etag=1947c83f9bae0387b9d725e24660fbc7', 'size': 5427274, 'public_key': None, 'sha256': '5821b6189f12edf628997dff952e213dddb47c0fe6c8ccc76bf92e19beeb088b', 'embedded': None, 'name': '1.JPG', 'exif': <EXIFObject{'date_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 14, 8, 27, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}>, 'resource_id': '372337915:3bdfd774d2ff0609aba6d4171bf803cb14b5234fc4f419664ae3b4be25653ad9', 'custom_properties': None, 'public_url': None, 'share': None, 'modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 30, 18, 1, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'created': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 30, 18, 1, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'photoslice_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 14, 8, 27, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), 'mime_type': 'image/jpeg', 'path': 'disk:/1.JPG', 'preview': 'https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/preview/8246f563f9b062d13613166ae059abe59bd8ccfa261b741808b92ae46d50d5e9/inf/t7ah81Nngc2pJHeTIiv0cYsvrYDjRFtlmwStYQuco5LzER2gLUdLrzsmFw217RIHbBOQ676MTmMOH1FHw5lKEQ%3D%3D?uid=372337915&filename=1.JPG&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fjpeg&owner_uid=372337915&tknv=v2&size=S&crop=0', 'comment_ids': <CommentIDsObject{'private_resource': '372337915:3bdfd774d2ff0609aba6d4171bf803cb14b5234fc4f419664ae3b4be25653ad9', 'public_resource': '372337915:3bdfd774d2ff0609aba6d4171bf803cb14b5234fc4f419664ae3b4be25653ad9'}>, 'type': 'file', 'media_type': 'image', 'md5': '1947c83f9bae0387b9d725e24660fbc7', 'revision': 1667158773261811}>]
```

а мне нужно оттуда лишь 'name': '1.JPG'
Есть у кого-то идеи как сделать этот фильтр?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это

```
print((list(y.get_files(limit = 2)))[0]["name"])
```

Comment: Привет @NIKITA, помогло, но я так понимаю тут достается переменная name из первой [0] ячейки списка
так вот, как бы мне так сделать чтоб все имена файлов записать в список? в дальнейшем мне нужно доставать одно из них.
files = list(y.get_files())
for i in files:
    print(files[i]["name"])
псевдо код

Comment: реализовал вот так
'''
files = list(y.get_files())
for p in files: 
    print(p["name"])
'''